# My loop code in javascript gives an "out of memory" error

Tags: javascript

I was learning Javascript and while i was making a loop code where every element in the array "tomultiply"  multiplies with itself and other elements and store the answers in an array "multiplelist".
But running my code keeps giving me an "out of memory" error.
Rectify my code if you will. It would be preferable that you understand the approach i am taking and correct it as it is. Thank you.

```
var multiplelist = [];
var tomultiply = [2, 3, 12, 8, 9];
var primary;
var secondary = 0;
var n = 0;
for (primary = tomultiply[n] ; primary = tomultiply[tomultiply.length - 1]; primary = tomultiply[n++]) {
    for (secondary = tomultiply[n] ; secondary = tomultiply[tomultiply.length - 1]; secondary = tomultiply[n++]) {
        var operation = primary * secondary;
        multiplelist.push(operation);
    }
}
console.log(multiplelist)
```

Comment: These loops will run forever because you are not setting any end conditions.

Comment: @JDunken that is unless `tomultiply[tomultiply.length - 1]` contains a falsy value (which is probably not what they meant to do, so yeah, you're right :) )

Comment: how do i do that? i am a beginner sorry

Comment: @1faiq1 `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. You want the latter in the second expression in the `for` loop (that is `primary = tomultiply[tomultiply.length - 1]` should really be `primary == tomultiply[tomultiply.length - 1]`, but that looks fishy as well, to be fair)

Comment: isn't the middle element inside the round brackets after 'for' defining the condition till when it should run?

Comment: @1faiq1 you are also assigning there not checking a condition

Answer (score 0):

You should use a condition in the second argument of for loop rather than assignment.

If I understand the intention of your code, I hope the below code should work for you.

```js
var multiplelist = [];
var tomultiply = [2, 3, 12, 8, 9];
var primary;
var secondary = 0;
var n = tomultiply.length;
for (let i = 0, primary = tomultiply[0] ; i < n; primary = tomultiply[++i]) {
    for (let j = 0, secondary = tomultiply[0] ; j < n; secondary = tomultiply[++j]) {
        var operation = primary * secondary;
        multiplelist.push(operation);
    }
}
console.log(multiplelist);
```